# NotImplementedError Use a queueing backend to enqueue jobs in the future

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I'm trying to use `ActiveJob` to queue jobs like email scheduling, but I get a

`NotImplementedError (Use a queueing backend to enqueue jobs in the future.` error

After a update is committed to the database, in my `model.rb` file

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Dirty
  require './app/jobs/email_scheduler_job'

  def send_approved_mail
    if self.approved_was == false && self.approved
      ArticleMailer.article_approved(self.owner).deliver_later
      EmailSchedulerJob.set(wait: 2.weeks).perform_later(owner)
    end
  end
end
```

and in my `EmailSchedulerJob`

```
class EmailSchedulerJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

Comment: Which ActiveJob's adapter are you using?

Comment: that might be the problem, I don't think I'm using any adapter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a queue adapter to enqueue jobs in the future. [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) is great in most cases, but it is quite complicated to set up. I think using sidekiq for email scheduling seems like an overkill. I would recommend using [sucker_punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch) for this.

To use sucker_punch as the adapter for ActiveJob, add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sucker_punch'
```

And then configure the backend to use sucker_punch:

```
# config/initializers/sucker_punch.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sucker_punch
end
```

You don't need to create a job for sending email. ActionMailer is integrated with ActiveJob so deliver_later should be enough.

Hope it helps :)